# Класс, в котором присутствует функция возвращающая структуру, определенную в отдельном файле

Tags: c++, классы, структуры

К примеру имеется следующий класс:

```
class A
{
private:
   int a;
public:
   somestruct func();
}
```

И некоторая структура somestruct, объявленная в файле struct.h. При компиляции кода выдается следующая ошибка:
func is not a member of A. Дело как я понимаю в неправильном объявлении структуры. Но как ее тогда корректно объявлять, чтобы можно было использовать функции возвращающие ее, в произвольном классе?

Comment: Где код, на который выдается ошибка? Почему он не приведен? И не надо здесь приводить по "по памяти"/"по мотивам". Приводите что-то более-менее реальное .

Comment: Если вы подключаете `struct.h`, то вопрос точно не в этом. Приведите, pls, [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Answer (score 0):

somestruct.h:

```
#pragma once


struct Foo{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "somestruct.h"

class Bar{
public:
    Bar():
        m_foo{}
    {
        m_foo.a = 3;
        m_foo.b = 5;
    }
    Bar(const Bar&) = default;
    Bar& operator=(const Bar&) = default;

    const Foo& getStruct() const{
        return m_foo;
    }
private:
    Foo m_foo;
};



int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    std::cout << "a: " << bar.getStruct().a << " b: " << bar.getStruct().b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
a: 3 b: 5
```

pro файл:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    somestruct.h
```